# as3 preloading for distribution

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloading

So the easiest way to preload in as3 would be to use an external .swf to load the main .swf. Since I will be distributing my game around the internet I can only use one .swf. What would be the best way to do this? Can I still use the external method but somehow combine the finished product into one .swf?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=946. Thanks for all the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to be distributing the game around the 'net? The easiest way would be to distribute the loader SWF and then keep the game SWF central to a single location somewhere on a server you control.

You get two benefits:

1. Less to distribute (the loader SWF is a cinch to hand out...and there's no real configuration needed).
2. One central location to update your game. That will ensure that everybody playing will be playing the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you want eveything to be contained in one SWF file, there is no way to also preload your game.

However, if you have server space somewhere, then you can create a preloader to load the actual meaty part of your game.